# problem in jdbc preparestatement

Tags: java, jdbc

i am geting error when i try to use following,why is it so?

```
ResultSet findByUsername(String tablename,String field,String value)
{ 
    pStmt = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM" + tablename +" WHERE ? = ? ");

    pStmt.setString(1,field);
    pStmt.setString(2,value);
    return(pStmt.executeQuery());

}
```

also i tried following , but its not working too

```
ResultSet findByUsername(String tablename,String field,String value)
{ 
    String sqlQueryString = " SELECT * FROM " + tablename +" WHERE " + field + "= ? ")     
     pStmt =cn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
    pStmt.setString(1, value);
    return(pStmt.executeQuery());

}
```

Comment: Perhaps assigning to pStmt and correcting the typos in the second example might help :)

Comment: The second doesn't compile. There's a closing parentheses instead of a semicolon at end of the SQL string. In future questions, please ensure that you're posting **REAL** code, copypasted from your "working" environment, to avoid unnecessary red herrings. Also please copypaste the exceptions since they tell something about the cause of the problem. Further, to fix your problem "invalid sql syntax", you'd also want to copy the *actual* SQL String here, i.e. do `System.out.println(sqlQueryString);` and copy its outcome here.

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
pStmt = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM" + tablename +" WHERE ? = ? ");
pStmt.setString(1, tablename);
pStmt.setString(2,field);
pStmt.setString(3,value);
```

Two `?`, but attempting to set three parameters.

In fact, you can't set things like names of tables and columns through prepared statement parameters.

You will also need to spell you variable names consistently and do something about the checked exceptions.

(When asking questions about code that causes errors, it's generally a good idea to quote the errors.)

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems here:

1. `"+ tablename +"` should be replaced with `?`
2. `WHERE ?=?` is totally wrong because of the conception of prepared statements. Prepared statements are precompiled statements, refering to the same table('s) and column('s) with different values under criterea (binded values). You can not bind a table or column name (or any other db object).

Answer (score 0):

When using `PreparedStatement`s you are only able to substitute in values, not the names of tables as you've attempts to do with " WHERE ? = ?".

Regarding your second code snippet, apart from the spelling mistake ("filed") I can't see why this would fail.  What error are you getting?

Comment: Not assigned the pStmt variable

The statement 

cn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);

should be

pStmt = cn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);

Comment: ERROR in findbyid You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 1' at line 1null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 1' at line 1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

In the first one you have 2 parameters in the query but you are adding a third, in the second statement you have a typo...

```
ResultSet findByUsername(String tablename,String field,String value)
{ 
    pStmt = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM" + tablename +" WHERE " + field" + = ? ");
    pStmt.setString(1,value);
    return(pStmt.executeQuery());    
}
```

Comment: I don't think `"field"` should be a string literal - `field` is passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

On second one try with single code on string value.

```
String sqlQueryString = " SELECT * FROM " + tablename +" WHERE " + filed + " = ? ");
```

use single code on comparing string values.
Give space between field and equal to.

thanks